# Elasticsearch nested and aggregation query with python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm relatively new to elasticsearch so pardon if it seems like a stupid question...
I'm trying to query my elastic to find all the documents that contain a word (tag) inside a nested json that holds array of objects..

example: 
{
...
"notes":  {
    ...
    "tags": {
        [{"n":100, "t": "data science"}, {"n":101, "t": "web development"}, {"n": 102, "t": "python"} ....]
    }
}
And I want to extract all the docuemnts (jsons) that have inside their tags one tag of data_science and one tag of python.

I'm using the regular elasticsearch libraby for this (on python)
and I've tried to use the aggs and nested docs but couldn't figure out 
how to combine them and get the query I need.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html

```
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch

es = Elasticsearch([{'host': 'localhost', 'port': 9200}])

body = '''
{
    "query": {
        "nested" : {
            "path" : "my_index",
            "query" : {
                "bool" : {
                    "must" : [
                    { "range" : {"my_index.notes.tags.t" : {"python": 2}} },
                    { "range" : {"my_index.notes.tags.t" : {"data science": 2}} }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "score_mode" : "avg"
        }
    }
}
'''

es.search(index="my_index", body=body)
```

Comment: The field that you are searching on, does it have nested mapping? If not you should change your mapping. About agg have checked nested agg query in elastic documentation?

Comment: How do I check if it has a nested mapping? and I actually did check, the code I sent is one of many tries I attempted...

Comment: You need to send post request to elastic, your_index/_mapping you can check your model.

Comment: Yeah already figured that out... and now after some research I understood that what I need is way more complex than just answering simple answer here ... Thanks alot tho and i'll keep looking (: